# Android listView

Tags: android, listview

I need help for my Android code.
I want to show all the elements of my web service, but because of the lines:

```
result = sb.toString();
jArray = new JSONArray(result);
return (JSONObject) jArray.get(0);
```

is only showing me one item.

I can not make a loop that goes iterates through my web service

Can you help me ?

Here are the lines of code for visiting:

```
private JSONObject lireJson()
{
    String myurl = "http://www.siomende.fr/anoll/Vala/ws/ws.php?action=getRdv";
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONArray jArray = null;
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(myurl);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        return (JSONObject) jArray.get(0);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        erreurWS = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
private void jsonToTextView(JSONObject json)
{
    try
    {
        // Getting JSON Object
        JSONObject c = json;
        // Storing JSON item in a Variable
        int idR = c.getInt("idR");
        String lieuR = c.getString("lieuR");
        String dateR = c.getString("dateR");
        String dureeR = c.getString("dureeR");
        p = new heure(lieuR, dateR, dureeR);
        p.setId(idR);
        genererTweets();
        for (int j = 0; j < c.getJSONArray("voiture").length(); j++)
        {
            JSONObject e = c.getJSONArray("voiture").getJSONObject(j);
            int idV = e.getInt("idV");
            String plaque = e.getString("plaque");
            String marque = e.getString("marque");
            Voiture voiture = new Voiture(plaque, marque);
            voiture.setIdV(idV);
            genererTweets();
            tweets.add(new Voiture(voiture.getMarqueV(), voiture.getPlaqueImmatriculationV()));
            p.ajoutVoiture(voiture);
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you use ``return (JSONObject) jArray.get(0);`` , it just return one item in array.

Comment: Yes i know , it just return one item and i want all items ...

Answer (score 0):

Make your method return type `JSONArray` and  instead of `return (JSONObject) jArray.get(0);` you just write `return (JSONArray)jArray;`
Then you will get an array that you can use in a for loop.

Comment: I try you'r solution Shekhar , but when i use (JSONArray)jArray i have an other error here :protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            JSONArray jsonProduits = lireJson(); 
            if (!erreurWS)
                jsonToTextView(jsonProduits);
            return null;
        } `

error for jsonProduits`"jsonToTextView(org.JSON.Object) in JSONPARSE cannot be applied to org.json.JSONArray "and if i try to write JSONObject jsonProduits = lireJson(); he want i write JSONArray ....

Comment: @krowry Please edit your question above. As you can see, code doesn't look nice in the comments.

Comment: try you'r solution Shekhar , but when i use `(JSONArray)jArray `i have an other error here :`protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) { JSONArray jsonProduits = lireJson(); if (!erreurWS) jsonToTextView(jsonProduits); return null; } `` error for jsonProduits`"jsonToTextView(org.JSON.Object) in JSONPARSE cannot be applied to org.json.JSONArray "and if i try to write `JSONObject jsonProduits = lireJson();` he want i write JSONArray ....

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Change function **lireJson** with return value is JSONArray :

```
private JSONArray lireJson(){

String myurl = "http://www.siomende.fr/anoll/Vala/ws/ws.php?action=getRdv";
InputStream is = null;
String result = "";
JSONArray jArray = null;
try
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(myurl);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
    jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    return jArray;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    erreurWS = true;
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
}
```

**2.** Convert JSONArray to JSONObject

```
private void jsonToTextView(JSONArray jArray){
try
{
    // Getting JSON Object
    for (int i = 0; i <jArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject obj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        //Do anything with obj
    }
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```